# Tycho build not finding 'org.eclipse.osgi' requirement

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, tycho

I have recently introduced a fragment project to a RCP app which provides JAX-WS components following a move from Java 8 to Java 11. The fragment host is `system.bundle`.

A simple test RCP project works as I want, the JAX-WS components are resolved and a web service can be called successfully. The project is on Github: https://github.com/pramsden/tycho-test.

Althought the target platform does have `org.eclipse.osgi` listed in its `Contents` view, I still get the following error message when the tycho build runs:

```
[DEBUG] No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.: [Unable to satisfy dependency from j17-jaxws-fragment 1.0.0.qualifier to osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.osgi 0.0.0.; No solutio
n found because the problem is unsatisfiable.]
[INFO] {osgi.os=win32, osgi.ws=win32, org.eclipse.update.install.features=true, osgi.arch=x86_64}
[ERROR] Cannot resolve project dependencies:
[ERROR]   Software being installed: j17-jaxws-fragment 1.0.0.qualifier
[ERROR]   Missing requirement: j17-jaxws-fragment 1.0.0.qualifier requires 'osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.osgi 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

Environment:

```
openjdk version "18.0.1.1" 2022-04-22
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 18.0.1.1+2-6)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.1.1+2-6, mixed mode, sharing)
Apache Maven 3.8.5 (3599d3414f046de2324203b78ddcf9b5e4388aa0)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.8.5
Java version: 18.0.1.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.1.1
Default locale: de_DE, platform encoding: UTF-8
```

I've tried using the option `-Dtycho.debug.resolver=true` but I couldn't see anything which helped me.

Comment: Consider responding to your previous questions before asking new ones. The example you linked is not minimal and uses different Tycho versions.

Comment: @howlger thanks. I didn't see that the tycho version in the pom and extensions.xml were different. That apparently fixed the 'Missing requirement' issue. I also needed to add the fragment to the `target-platform-configuration` section. Build is now successful.